# run PHP script (target hidden) but link to PDF (not hidden)

Tags: php, html, css

Community,

I would like to run a script when you click a link, but this shouldn't open in a new frame, that's why I added the following:

```
<iframe style="display:none;" name="target"></iframe>

<a href="script.php" target="target">
```

The script now executes without popping a blank page, joy. But  I want the same link to open a PDF file.

```
<a href="pdf/cesar.pdf" target="_blank" > click here to download </a>
```

But now the PDF doesn't show, as the target frame is hidden. I can't seem to combine these two. Can someone help me out on this?

Cheers!

Cesar.

Comment: Why are the links different? Are you saying one works and one doesn't? Set your response MIME type to something like `application/octet-stream` if you don't want the browser to attempt to display the file.

Comment: Maybe look at Xhr/AJAX? You don't need an iframe to invoke a request to the server like that.

Comment: It sounds like you're over-engineering this.  If you want one link to (1) run a PHP script and (2) open a PDF then just have a normal link which directs the user to a PHP script and have that script *return* the PDF when it's done.

Comment: Thanks, David! Fixed it with  added it to the PHP script.

Comment: @Cesar: Great!  I'll add it as an answer below in case anybody finds this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be over-engineering this.  Consider the high-level requirements:

> The link needs to:
>
> 1. Execute PHP code
> 2. Open a PDF file

This *sounds like* two actions, but from the perspective of the client it's really only one action... open the PDF file.  The rest is up to server-side code.

So create one link to perform that one action:

```
<a href="getPDF.php">click here to download</a>
```

As long as `getPDF.php` returns a PDF file, the client will never know the difference.  What that PHP code does *before* returning that file is up to you.  You can have all the code you want in that file, as long as the resulting response is returning the PDF file back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

With the display none it will never show up, you probably should use jQuery, I'd added an ID to the "a"

```
<iframe style="display:none;" name="target"></iframe>

<a href="script.php" id="openPdf" target="target">
```

and when click:

```
$(document).on("click","#openPDF",function(){
 $("iframe").css("display","block");
});
```